# +Flattening the curve ...

Tags: geometry, projection

Edited to correct errors identified below:

I have a cylinder with r = 1 and a central axis given by y = (√3)x/6. I think this is a cylinder intersecting the xz-plane at π/6. I am pretty sure that the intersection is an ellipse, in which case the formula for the intersection of the cylinder with the xz-plane would be (x^2)/(a^2) + (z^2)/(b^2) = 1, and in this case, I think a=2, b=1. Please confirm that I have not blundered this too badly.

So far; so good.

Suppose I were to "mark" my cylinder with the intersection and unroll it into a plane. What is the curve created by the mark?

Here's why I'm interested in this question. I have to cut a piece of stove pipe with an eight inch radius such that the stove pipe will make a thirty degree angle with the adjacent surface. I can unroll the stove pipe into a flat sheet, but I need to draw the cut line on it.

Thanks for the help,

Chris.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [mathjax basic tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and enhance your question.

Comment: I am not yet clear on your question. The central axis of the cylinder is $y = ax$ instead of $x = 0$ or $y = 0$ and its radius is $r$. Why would that make the intersection with $z$ plane an ellipse?

Comment: or did you mean with $y$ plane and/or $x$ plane?

Comment: Hi, Yes. I think you're right. The intersection I seek is with the xz-plane.

Comment: @Math Lover, Can you review my above edits? I think the statement of the problem makes sense now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: As per equation of central axis, $y = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{6} x$. So the angle that the central axis makes with $y$ plane is $\theta = \arctan  \frac{\sqrt{3}}{6}$. The angle that you are interested in then is $90^0 - \theta$. None of these angles are $\frac{\pi}{6}$.

Comment: Point 2 - when you cut open the pipe, the intersection that you marked on the pipe will simply be a straight line. What is your objective? Are you trying to find its length?

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment.

The cylinder equation is given by

$$
C(x,y,z) = \left(x+\frac{y}{2 \sqrt{3}}\right)^2-\frac{13}{12} \left(x^2+y^2+z^2-1\right)=0
$$

The intersection with the plane $x=0$ gives

$$
C_x(y,z) = \frac{12 y^2}{13}+z^2-1=0
$$

and with the plane $y=0$

$$
C_y(x,z) = \frac{x^2}{13}+z^2-1=0
$$